# URL parser doen't recognize all valid inputs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

The URL recognizer stops at the `'` character, yet this is a valid character in URLs.

Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem

On a related note, wrapping the URL in `<a href="...">` doesn't help either; somehow the sanitizing process filters out the URL it thinks is faulty:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem">this is (not) a link</a>
```

Yields:

```
<p>this is (not) a link</p>
```

(Currently: [this is (not) a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).)

Answer (score 4):

Instead, wrap it in [Markdown syntax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

```
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem)
```

Produces
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem

Comment: ...or make the editor do it for you: paste the URL, select it, hit Ctrl-L, paste it again. Of course, in this very example a nice text rather than the bare URL looks better anyhow! Like: *"[Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) for Rice's theorem..."*. So: type that nice title, select it, hit Ctrl-L, paste the URL.